# Jndi bind Java null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jndi

I am learning JNDI from video tutorial. And i try bind my context but i get Java NullPointerException.

There is error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.generateNamingException(FSContext.java:809)
> at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.generateNamingException(FSContext.java:783)
> at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.setBindings(RefFSContext.java:602)
> at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.bindObject(RefFSContext.java:338)
> at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.bind(RefFSContext.java:169)
> at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.bind(FSContext.java:167)
> at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:425)
> at jndi.CustomerJndi.main(CustomerJndi.java:23)

and there is my code

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {

    Hashtable<String,String> environment= new Hashtable<String,String>();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"file:D:/Users");
    Context context=new InitialContext(environment);

    context.bind("Jea",new Boss("Boss","Boosovic"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm no expert but just created something like that.

Have you tried changing the URL

```
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"file:D:/Users");
```

TO

```
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"file:///D:/Users");
```